# What does the whole number 2 do in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

In:

```
print("Total cost of laptops: $%2.5f" % price)
```

The price variable is equal to 9156.5 and I know what the decimal does in the code but what does the whole number (2) do?

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Somehow, given the numbers and the fact that it's a price, I think `%5.2f` makes more sense.

Comment: The 2 indicates the total minimum field length in the output, including the decimal dot. Given that the format requires 5 decimal figures, there will be *at least* 6 characters in the field (5 decimals, plus the decimal dot; and probably a leading zero or some other number).

Comment: The `2` is not going to affect the formatting in this since the five decimal places already ensure that the string is longer than 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This notation

> %2.5f

Is for String formatting of floats. Anything after the `.` indicates how many decimal points from the number will be displayed (in this case five)

```
print("Total cost of laptops: $%2.5f" % price)
Total cost of laptops: $9156.50000
```

I have never seen formatting that included significant digits, it seems you might be seeing code from an older version of string formatting.

However, I tried it out and got some funny results:

```
print("Total cost of laptops: $%11.5f" %  9156.5)
Total cost of laptops: $ 9156.50000
```

```
print("Total cost of laptops: $%20.5f" %  9156.5)
Total cost of laptops: $          9156.50000
```

So it would seem that the number before the `.` just ensures the size of your string is at least that length.

Comment: Please provide a concrete (documented/referenced) answer, rather than 'it would seem that ...'.  That's not an acceptable answer.

Comment: @S3DEV this is an acceptable answer, what you said is not true. The answer can get better, but it's fine as of now.